# Error in command update-migration, Entity Framework 3.15, Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have defined my template and referenced in the DbContext but when I run the update-database command it generates the error: The "InstitutionContact" object cannot be found because it does not exist or does not have permissions.

Verifying the migration that it creates, it is clearly seen that the **error is generated because it creates an update migration** of a table that does not exist and not of a table creation migration. How can I avoid creating an update migration if the table I am trying to update does not exist? How can I create the table I need?

**Migration**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;
```

namespace DegreeProjectsSystem.DataAccess.Migrations
{
public partial class AddTableInstitutionContacts : Migration
{
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
name: "FK_InstitutionContact_InstitutionContactCharges_InstitutionContactChargeId",
table: "InstitutionContact");

```
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
            name: "FK_InstitutionContact_Institutions_InstitutionId",
            table: "InstitutionContact");

        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
            name: "FK_InstitutionContact_People_PersonId",
            table: "InstitutionContact");

        migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
            name: "InstitutionContact",
            newName: "InstitutionContacts");

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
            name: "PersonId",
            table: "InstitutionContacts",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(int),
            oldNullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
            name: "InstitutionId",
            table: "InstitutionContacts",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(int),
            oldNullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
            name: "InstitutionContactChargeId",
            table: "InstitutionContacts",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(int),
            oldNullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
            name: "Id",
            table: "InstitutionContacts",
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: 0)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1");

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<bool>(
            name: "Active",
            table: "InstitutionContacts",
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: false);

        migrationBuilder.AddPrimaryKey(
            name: "PK_InstitutionContacts",
            table: "InstitutionContacts",
            column: "Id");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_InstitutionContacts_InstitutionContactChargeId",
            table: "InstitutionContacts",
            column: "InstitutionContactChargeId");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_InstitutionContacts_PersonId",
            table: "InstitutionContacts",
            column: "PersonId");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_InstitutionContacts_InstitutionId_PersonId_InstitutionContactChargeId",
            table: "InstitutionContacts",
            columns: new[] { "InstitutionId", "PersonId", "InstitutionContactChargeId" },
            unique: true);

        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_InstitutionContacts_InstitutionContactCharges_InstitutionContactChargeId",
            table: "InstitutionContacts",
            column: "InstitutionContactChargeId",
            principalTable: "InstitutionContactCharges",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);

        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_InstitutionContacts_Institutions_InstitutionId",
            table: "InstitutionContacts",
            column: "InstitutionId",
            principalTable: "Institutions",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);

        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_InstitutionContacts_People_PersonId",
            table: "InstitutionContacts",
            column: "PersonId",
            principalTable: "People",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
            name: "FK_InstitutionContacts_InstitutionContactCharges_InstitutionContactChargeId",
            table: "InstitutionContacts");

        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
            name: "FK_InstitutionContacts_Institutions_InstitutionId",
            table: "InstitutionContacts");

        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
            name: "FK_InstitutionContacts_People_PersonId",
            table: "InstitutionContacts");

        migrationBuilder.DropPrimaryKey(
            name: "PK_InstitutionContacts",
            table: "InstitutionContacts");

        migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
            name: "IX_InstitutionContacts_InstitutionContactChargeId",
            table: "InstitutionContacts");

        migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
            name: "IX_InstitutionContacts_PersonId",
            table: "InstitutionContacts");

        migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
            name: "IX_InstitutionContacts_InstitutionId_PersonId_InstitutionContactChargeId",
            table: "InstitutionContacts");

        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "Id",
            table: "InstitutionContacts");

        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "Active",
            table: "InstitutionContacts");

        migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
            name: "InstitutionContacts",
            newName: "InstitutionContact");

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
            name: "PersonId",
            table: "InstitutionContact",
            nullable: true,
            oldClrType: typeof(int));

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
            name: "InstitutionId",
            table: "InstitutionContact",
            nullable: true,
            oldClrType: typeof(int));

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
            name: "InstitutionContactChargeId",
            table: "InstitutionContact",
            nullable: true,
            oldClrType: typeof(int));

        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_InstitutionContact_InstitutionContactCharges_InstitutionContactChargeId",
            table: "InstitutionContact",
            column: "InstitutionContactChargeId",
            principalTable: "InstitutionContactCharges",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);

        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_InstitutionContact_Institutions_InstitutionId",
            table: "InstitutionContact",
            column: "InstitutionId",
            principalTable: "Institutions",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);

        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_InstitutionContact_People_PersonId",
            table: "InstitutionContact",
            column: "PersonId",
            principalTable: "People",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    }
}
```

}

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace DegreeProjectsSystem.Models
{
    public class InstitutionContact
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Debe seleccionar una Institución")]
        public int InstitutionId { get; set; }
        
        [Display(Name = "Institución")]
        //Foreign key
        [ForeignKey("InstitutionId")]
        public Institution Institution { get; set; }
        
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Debe seleccionar un Contacto")]
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        
        [Display(Name = "Contacto")]
        //Foreign key
        [ForeignKey("PersonId")]
        public Person Person { get; set; }
        
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Debe seleccionar el cargo del Contacto")]
        public int InstitutionContactChargeId { get; set; }
        
        [Display(Name = "Cargo")]
        //Foreign key
        [ForeignKey("InstitutionContactChargeId")]
        public InstitutionContactCharge InstitutionContactCharge { get; set; }
        
        [Display(Name = "Estado")]
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try delete the code inside the Up method and down method in your migrate file. then run the command Update-database

Comment: The solution did not work, it does not generate error but does not create the table either.

Comment: Have you deleted any of your migrations ever? Bevause it seems like you did. Your model snapshot probably already contains the definition of that table.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

- I removed all migrations from the project.
- I removed the
  database.
- I generated the first migration.
- Before running the update-migration I modified some primary key
  relationships that  generated an error for having created cascade
  deletions by default, changing onDelete:
  ReferentialAction.Cascade to onDelete: ReferentialAction.NoAction.
- Create a new migration to rebuild the database.